# Using Chart.js in Web Worker

Tags: javascript, chart.js, web-worker

I am trying to use Worker for drawing the Chart using Chart.js, as mentioned on the Chart.js page:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/performance/
Section: Parallel rendering with web workers (Chrome only)

But in the `worker.js` file I get an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
```

I have below code in `worker.js`:

```
onmessage = function(event) {
    const {canvas, config} = event.data;
    const chart = new Chart(canvas, config); // Error for Chart 

    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;
    chart.resize();
};
```

Comment: Are you providing the offline canvas object when dispatching the event as per the docs?

Comment: Yes, I am sending the offline canvas to web worker. As I want to have parellel processing on multiple charts at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the library inside your worker's script.

For this you can use the [`importScripts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) method.

Also be sure to use the v.3 of the library as v2.x was expecting a DOM HTMLElement, and finally, it seems you need to set a global `window` variable (set it to `self`) in your Worker:

```js
const worker_script = `
  const window = self;
  importScripts("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0-beta/chart.min.js");

  onmessage = function(event) {
    const {canvas, config} = event.data;
    const chart = new Chart(canvas, config); // Error for Chart 

    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 500;
    chart.resize();
  };
`;
const worker_url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([worker_script], { type: "text/javascript" }));

const worker = new Worker(worker_url);
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").transferControlToOffscreen();
const config = { type:"line",data:{labels:["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],datasets:[{label:"My First Dataset",data:[65,59,80,81,56,55,40],fill:false,borderColor:"rgb(75, 192, 192)",lineTension:0.1}]} };

worker.postMessage({ canvas, config }, [canvas]);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks. Able to import Chart.js but getting error `Chart.min.js- Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'width' property on 'OffscreenCanvas': Value is not of type 'unsigned long'.`